# Custom dictionary object fails unexpectedly in method?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was making a lookup table for the sizes of various characters in various font sizes. I made a dictionary like functionality (I call them associative arrays. Is that a thing? Do people use that phrase?)

my associative array:

```
class assocarray(object):
    def __init__(self,name,value):
        self.name=name
        self.value=value
        self.hasnext=False
    def push(self,name,value):
        if(self.name==name):
            self.value=value
        elif(self.hasnext):
            self.next.push(name,value)
        else:
            self.next = assocarray(name,value)
            self.hasnext = True
    def findname(self,name):
        if(self.name == name):
            return self.value
        elif(self.hasnext):
            return self.next.findname(name)
        else:
            return False
    def getlistparams(self,list):
        list.append(self.name)
        if(self.hasnext):
            self.next.getlistparams(list)
    def fillassocarray(self,arr):
        fill = []
        arr.getlistparams(fill)
        for var in fill:
            arr.push(var,self.findname(var))
class myvars(object):
    def __init__(self,type):
        self.empty=True
    def setvar(self,name,value):
        if(self.empty):
            self.hash = assocarray(name,value)
            self.empty=False
        else:
            self.hash.push(name,value)
    def getvar(self,name):
        if(self.empty):
            return False
        else:
            return self.hash.findname(name)
```

Using it in other places I know that it works just fine.

```
global reftable

def init_reftable():
    reftable = myvars("reference table")
    reftable.setvar(10,myvars("font size"))
    reftable.getvar(10).setvar("a",(3,4))
    ...
    reftable.setvar(11,myvars("font size"))
    test = reftable.getvar(11)
    print "test: %r" % test # these 2 lines never execute?
    print "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" #
    ...
    reftable.getvar(11).setvar("<",(3,5))
    ...
```

this reference table will be interfaced with another object in the module that calculate the size of strings in whatever font:

```
class font_table(object):
    def __init__(self,font_size=False):
        init_reftable()
        if(font_size!=False):
            self.size=font_size
            self.set_size=True
        else:
            self.set_size=False
    def charsize(self,letter):
        if(self.set_size):
            return reftable.getvar(self.size).getvar(letter)
        else:
            return False
    def charsize2(self,size,letter):
        return reftable.getvar(size).getvar(letter)
    def getstringlength(self,the_str):
        if(self.set_size):
            size = len(the_str)
            list = the_str.split()
            width=0
            height=0
            for i in range(0,size+1):
                the_chr = charsize(list[i])
                width+=the_chr[0]
                if(the_chr[1]>height):
                    height=the_chr[1]
            return (width,height)
        else:
            return False
    def getstringlength2(self,font_size,the_str):
        size = len(the_str)
        list = the_str.split()
        width=0
        height=0
        for i in range(0,size+1):
            the_chr = charsize2(font_size,list[i])
            width+=the_chr[0]
            if(the_chr[1]>height):
                height=the_chr[1]
        return (width,height)
```

tester code:

```
my_table = font_table(16)
print "size of string: \"sweet pie of mine\": %r" % my_table.getstringlength("sweet pie of mine")
```

trying to run a test on this code I get:

```
me:src me$ python test-font-table.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-font-table.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_table = font_table(16)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/cup-robot-project/cup-robot-3/src/fonttable.py", line 1184, in __init__
    init_reftable()
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/cup-robot-project/cup-robot-3/src/fonttable.py", line 211, in init_reftable
    reftable.getvar(11).setvar("<",(3,5))
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'setvar'
```

That last part is not surprising: when reftable.getvar() can't find a value it returns False (not using False as a legitimate value hasn't hurt me yet). But I don't understand why it would anyway.

Comment: You need to show the code for your custom object, otherwise we can't possibly know what's wrong with it.

Comment: What is a `reftable`, what is the code that interfaces with it in your other modules.  With globals you have to pay attention to how you're changing it.  Seems likely that you have an instance of `reftable = (some function that returns a boolean)`

Comment: If you know that `getvar` returns a `boolean False` when it can't be found why is the failure unexpected? you are calling `setvar` on a boolean return value? Isn't this how you designed `reftable` to behave?

Comment: the failure is unexpected because its in an object that just adds other data to its collection ad nauseum, and in a function that just adds data. plus `reftable.setvar(11)` was called, so it should exist. Plus, it fails in the middle of adding data. not at the first try.

Comment: I guess the real question is (among others) is how do I troubleshoot Python failing to add/create an object?

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get a `TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments` on the line `list = the_str.split(self.size,str="")` of the `fontable.getstringlength()` method. If I "fix" that with `list = the_str.split()`, I get a different error further down because the function `charsize()` isn't defined. The important point is I **don't** get the `AttributeError` you say you're getting.

Comment: I know this is not related to the error you're getting, but is there a reason you're writing your own associative array, rather than just using a dictionary? That would probably make your code much easier and less prone to strange errors.

Comment: I'm new to python and I just found it easier to just make something than find out how something worked. I do want an answer to this because it will inevitably show up again somewhere else. Besides doesn't dicts throw exceptions if a key isn't found? Mine just returns false.

Comment: @jasondancks: You can use `dict.get` to get either the value stored under a given key, or a default value (such as `None`) if the key is not in the dictionary. But often the exception is more useful, if your code expects the key to be there and can't handle the default value. The exception you're reporting comes from exactly that situation, where your hand-brewed dict-like object is returning `False` when you expect it to return something else. Would getting an `KeyError` be any worse in that situation?

Comment: I felt there could be, if I felt there was a good chance a key might not exist (or if I wrote code expecting this) I can quickly handle it, perhaps do something useful with the information. I would have to know what type or error I'm expecting if I used a dict. If you don't have the docs in front of you (A common occurence) you're screwed. And since I wrote it there's little chance something screwy would happen. IDK why this is occurring. It shouldn't be. I suspect something about Python and recursion.

Comment: plus, my code requires a string telling me what its being used for. Very handy info to have around that I can expect to be there. I'm not saying its better, but arguably less cryptic than a dict